# Configuring access to private repositories in devcontainers

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, configuration

I would like to start using devcontainers ([Visual Studio Code - Remote Containers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers)) on some internal projects. These projects all need access to internal package repositories (npm, maven, nuget, docker, apt, yum etc.) during their build, which generally requires providing appropriate config files (`~/.npmrc`, `~/.m2/settings.xml`, `~/.config/NuGet/NuGet.Config`, `/etc/apt/sources.list` etc.).

Now for convenience it might be easiest to just embed the necessary configs into the base image, but I don't want everybody to just use the same credentials, nor do I want to have the credentials stored in a base image somewhere.

VSCode automatically supports forwarding git-credential-helper and ssh-agent, and copies .gitconfig by default, but not for other tools. It also provides a way to check out additional “dotfiles” repository into the container and run a script, but again, repository is not the right tool here.

Are there better options for injecting tool credentials into a devcontainer that are not too configuration-intensive for the team members while still using their own credentials?

Comment: Did you work out a solution for this?

Comment: @GaTechThomas, no, I didn't. The easiest is probably to use environment variables with credentials and tell everybody to set them, but it's not very user-friendly.

Comment: Solution can be found at https://liammartens.medium.com/using-your-local-npmrc-inside-a-vs-code-development-container-e31f2b36a335 , basically mount your `.npmrc` inside your container `"source=${localEnv:HOME}${localEnv:USERPROFILE}/.npmrc,target=/home/node/.npmrc,type=bind,consistency=cached"` (Same can be done with the other ones)